# How to show only name in input box but name and number in dropdown list in select element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

Html5 select element should:

- Show account name and number in dropdown list.
- If account is selected, only number should displayed in box
- Number should stored in value on selection

I tried code below in Chrome.
After selecting `13111 Receiveables`  it shows `13111 Receiveables` in input box.

How to fix this so that after selecting `13111 Receiveables`  only accont number
`13111` is shown in field ?

Bootstrap 3 ,jquery, jquery-ui, ASP.NET MVC4 with Razor view engine are used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Account number:
    <select>
        <option label='' value=''></option>
        <option value='13111' label='13111 Receiveables'>13111</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified @arsho's code

I believe you were looking for this:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <br> Account number:
  <select id="account_select">
        <option id="optId" label='' value=''></option>
        <option value='13111' label='13111 Receiveables'>13111</option>
    <option value='13112' label='13112 Receiveables'>13112</option>
    <option value='13113' label='13113 Rssseceiveables'>13113</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#account_select").on("change", function() {
    $this_value = $(this).val();

    $("#optId").text($this_value);
    $("#optId").attr("selected",true);


  });

});
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Change the **HTML** as:

```
    <body>
      <input placeholder="Account number will be shown upon selection" type="text" id="account_number" />
      <br> Account number:
      <select id="account_select">
          <option label='' value=''></option>
          <option value='13111' label='13111 Receiveables'>13111</option>
      </select>
    </body>
```

In **jQuery** add the following snippet:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#account_select").on("change", function() {
        $this_value = $(this).val();
        $("#account_number").val($this_value);
      });
    });
```

See in live codedpen http://codepen.io/arsho/pen/GZErBL

Comment: This requires separate fields for data entry and data display. Screen is small and there are lot of such select elements. Duplicating number of elements for data entry is not possible. 
How to use single field and preferably without javascript?